# How to pluralize human_attribute_name with Rails 5 and I18n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-i18n

I want to translate and pluralize an attribute name in my App.

So, for the my api_key attribute, I have the translation "Clef API".

I pluralize the attribute name with `Mymodel.human_attribute_name(:api_key).pluralize(2)` and get as a result : `"Clef APIs"`

But in french, the plural for "Clef API" is "Clefs API"

So I tried to give plural translations in my YML but it does not work and I stillget the transaltion for "One" pluralized with an 's' at the end.

fr.yml :

```
activerecord:
  attributes:
    mymodel:
      api_key:
        one: "Clef API"
        other: "Clefs API"
```

Can I get `Mymodel.human_attribute_name(:api_key).pluralize(2)` to return `"Clefs API"` ?

If not, how could I translate and pluralize my atributes name ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add customized plural words in **Inflectors** at `config/initializers/inflections.rb`. You can see the code example below:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:fr) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'Clef API', 'Clefs API'
end
```

Comment: Inflectors are indeed a nice way to do this.

But you have to be careful : `pluralize` and `singularize` use :en as default locale, not the current I18n.locale.

So, to use Inflectors here, I also have to add the locale: `Mymodel.human_attribute_name(:api_key).pluralize(2, I18n.locale)`.

Answer (score 6):

Just after posting my question I though I should check the doc for [human_attribute_name](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/human_attribute_name/class) for a hint. And it did solve my problem...

Turns out `human_attribute_name` handles pluralization directly. It accepts an `options` hash with the key `:count` that does trigger the plural like with other I18n methods.

So, it's as simple as doing `Mymodel.human_attribute_name(:api_key, count: 2)`